# Can AWS Glue delete Parquet data when corresponding data in S3 is deleted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, parquet, amazon-athena

For an upcoming project, I will be using AWS Glue to retrieve data from CSVs stored in S3 and convert it to Apache Parquet format for querying via AWS Athena.

The flow above accomplishes storing the data and getting it ready for querying. However, the data that I will be storing in S3 (the CSV files) can also be deleted by the user that owns the data. So, what I am unsure about is whether or not a Glue job can be run each time a file is deleted to remove the corresponding data, which lives in the Parquet file(s) that it had initially created.

I read that Parquet files are immutable and if changes occur in the underlying data, the file must be overwritten completely. So, that's why I am unsure if this is possible.

Can this be done?

I haven't tried to set this up yet. I am asking here for advice so that I can go about doing so correctly.

Comment: If writing to parquet is for only reading it through athena, you can directly create a crawler on csv files to create catalog tables directly. If you create tables on top of source files directly then the deletes or updates will be reflected immediatly.

Comment: there are multiple ways to prevent this. Don't provide access to user and to only IAM role. Also add a bucket policy to prevent any data.

Comment: @SrikanthKantamaneni ok. I was thinking of doing that initially but was afraid that querying with that might not be as performant on large datasets. I’ll give that a try then. Thanks!